# Init errors on solr 4.4.0 : No such core

Tags: apache, tomcat, core-data, solr, solr4

I added a new core by duplicating the default collection1 folder, renamed the folder to "core_name" changed the core name in the core.properties and solorconfig.xml. I reloaded the core using ?action=RELOAD&core=core0 by mistake. I then reloaded it by using ?action=RELOAD&core=core_name. The admin page came up and i saw the newly added core but there was n error concerning the core0 i tried reloading before. I then unloaded the core "core_name" and i reloaded. I got the error below. PLEASE HELP!!!

HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /solr/. Reason:

```
{msg=SolrCore 'collection1' is not available due to init failure: No such core: collection1,trace=org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: SolrCore 'collection1' is not available due to init failure: No such core: collection1
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.getCore(CoreContainer.java:860)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:251)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:158)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:455)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:533)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1075)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:384)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1009)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:368)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(BlockingHttpConnection.java:53)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:942)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1004)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:640)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:72)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:264)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
```

Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: No such core: collection1
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.reload(CoreContainer.java:740)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminHandler.handleReloadAction(CoreAdminHandler.java:769)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminHandler.handleRequestBody(CoreAdminHandler.java:171)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:135)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.handleAdminRequest(SolrDispatchFilter.java:611)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:209)
    ... 26 more
,code=500}
Powered by Jetty://

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced something similar before on SOLR 4.4.0. Remove the core folder not found. 'Collection1' in your case. And then restart SOLR. SOLR might still keep giving you this error if you don't restart it.

That should work.